# I need to display all the class name of my java code

Tags: java

I tried to display by finding the string but i am not able to print the class name.this is my java code.i need to display class names like crosscutting themes,flag,log,basetheme,register,assign.

```
            class Theme {

                 }
          class crosscuttingtheme extends Theme{ 


            }
           class flag extends crosscuttingtheme{
                 public flag()
                        {
                    }
                    }
               class log extends crosscuttingtheme{

                      public log()
                         {
                          }
                                       }

                       class basetheme extends Theme
                                                { 


                                                        } 
                         class register extends basetheme
                              {
                       public register()
                               {
                                     }
                             }
                       class unregister extends basetheme{
                 public unregister()
                  {
                       }
                       }
                 class assignmarks extends basetheme{
                   public assignmarks()
                  {
                   }
                 }
```

Comment: Unless you format your code correctly and tell us what you want exactly, we cannot be of much help

Comment: i need to display the class names of the above program by reading this file

Comment: use reflections - see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(getClass().getName());
```

Comment: it is giving only the main class name

Comment: Post what your main looks like. Every object has a getClass() method. You should be able to take what I showed you and get what you need. If you still can't then post your main code and I'll see if I can guide you further.

Comment: 'public class theme { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      
   }     
}

Comment: Your main does nothing. What are you trying to do? You don't have a reference to an object to print the class name. Is this a class assignment or something? Please give a little more information so I will know how to answer.

Comment: i have to read this file using another code and display the class names..this is for my project

Comment: So the code you posted above is actually a file that you have to read and output the classnames?

Comment: You should try to write some code yourself and when you have a problem, post what your code looks like and what you don't understand. What you are doing right now is posting a blank main method with no work done and a problem to solve. I understand that it can seem overwhelming. Try to break it into sub problems. Smaller problems that make up the whole. Then try to solve each smaller problem and if you get stuck post your issue on here.

Answer (score 0):

checkout https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

```
void printClassName(Object obj) {
     System.out.println("The class of " + obj +
                        " is " + obj.getClass().getName());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To print out the name of any class, you just have to get an **instance** of that class, then call `.getClass().getName()` on it. For example, for your `Theme` class, you could do as follows:

```
Theme theme = new Theme();
System.out.println(theme.getClass().getName());
```

This will print out the name of the class, 'Theme';